# Capture date from file name as a parameter then rename the file

Tags: vb.net, parsing, filenames

Not sure if this is possible but each day a file will be sent to a folder: Z:\prod\DataProcessing\temp

The file name will look like this: 20230215_UniqueProductsFile.txt

I am wondering if it is possible to
a) search the folder for the version of the file with a date
b) capture the date to use as a parameter for another process
c) rename the file to UniqueProductsFile.txt overwriting the existing one in the folder from the previous days load

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> a) search the folder for the version of the file with a date b) capture the date to use as a parameter for another process

This is possible using the IO.File.Exists method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists)) to check if the file exists. For example:

```vb
Private Function UniqueProductsFileExistsByDate(directory As String, value As DateTime, ByRef output As String) As Boolean
    Dim filename = $"{value:yyyyMMdd}_UniqueProductsFile.txt"
    Dim path = IO.Path.Combine(directory, filename)
    Dim fileExists = IO.File.Exists(path)
    If (fileExists) Then
        output = path
    End If
    Return fileExists
End Function
```

> c) rename the file to UniqueProductsFile.txt

This is possible using IO.File.Move ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move)) where the first argument is the ByRef value set in the `UniqueProductsFileExistsByDate` method and the second argument is the new name:

```vb
Dim directory = IO.Path.Combine("Z:", "prod", "DataProcessing", "temp")
Dim value = DateTime.Today
Dim path As String
If (UniqueProductsFileExistsByDate(directory, value, path)) Then
    Dim newPath = IO.Path.Combine(directory, "UniqueProductsFile.txt")
    IO.File.Move(path, newPath)
End If
```